# PDF File Reading using Laravel PHP Error : readfile($path): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, file

```
public function open()
{
    $path = '2020/March/tes.pdf';
    if (Storage::exists($path)) {
        Storage::get($path);
        // dd(Storage::files('2020\March'));
        echo readfile($path);
        //echo ini_get("open_basedir");
    } else {
        Echo ('File didnt exist');
        }
}
```

> I'm new to web programming, here i intend to open a .pdf file in app/public/2020/March, file and path are exist, but i cant open the file, it says "readfile(2020/March/tes.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory".
>   I tried tutorials on the internet, linking storage, storing in app/public, caching config, clearing config, change default filesystem to public.
>   Thank You.

Comment: try use absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because your path is not correct. To access your file inside public folder use `public_path()` function

As per Laravel Documenation:

> The `public_path` function returns the fully qualified path to the
>   public directory. You may also use the `public_path` function to
>   generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the public
>   directory

**Change**

```
 $path = '2020/March/tes.pdf';
```

**to**

```
$path = public_path("2020/March/tes.pdf");
```